# Java - Thread.sleep freezes my UI. How do I get around this?

Tags: java, multithreading, sleep, freeze, runnable

When I fire off the command "wait", I want a pause for 1000 milliseconds. For example, if my script contains the following:

```
print("first message")
wait()
print("second message <after the delay>")
```

I would want a 1000ms delay between the two messages.

However, my problem is that it freezes the whole application for the 1000ms, then fires off both messages at the same exact time.

Here is my code: (Ive been searching this site for solutions and came across multiple answers that said that I need to create my own separate Thread in order to do this:

```
       if(command.equals("wait")) {
            MyRunnable myRunnable = new MyRunnable();
            Thread t = new Thread(myRunnable);
            t.start();
        }
```

and here is my separate Thread inner class:

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    public MyRunnable() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(2000);
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Edit: The print statements work fine thats why i left them out. But im new to java and i noticed that the run() statement doesnt work so i put it in the constructor

Comment: Dude, I know RS drains people's brains but anyway, when doing illicit stuff you usually hide those details from public view (letting alone it is completely unrelated to the question).

Comment: There is a thread.sleep in the constructor? where are the print statements?

Answer (score 3):

Remove the sleep() call from your constructor - it's unnecessary and will block your main thread when called, because the constructor is executed synchronously.

Your runnable doesn't have any print statements, and that's what needs to do the printing.  Try something like this:

```
public class DelayedPrinter implements Runnable {
private String text;
public MyRunnable(String text) {
    this.text = text;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    catch (Exception e){}
    print(text);
}
```

And call it like this:

```
new Thread(new DelayedPrinter(text)).start();
```

I don't know what scripting tool you're using, but you command might look like:

```
delayPrint("second message");
```

How you wire that up with the previous line should be fairly simple.

Comment: It doesnt work at all when i remove the sleep method from the constructor :(

Comment: See edits. Aldo you've left out the code calling your runnable, so it's guesswork here

Comment: +1 for the effort to help against all odds :)

Comment: This might sound terrible, but can you show me how to call it?

Comment: I think this guy deserves the answer credit, don't you?

Answer (score 0):

Wait will not do what you think. It pushes the current thread to a so-called wait state, which can be notified by other threads. It's meant to be used for inter-thread communication.

See more here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#wait()

In the second case you create and start a new thread which will sleep for 2 secs and die without doing anything. If you write to the console on the original thread this won't have any effect.

If want you want is a simple delay between the console.outs try this:

```
println("first message");
Thread.sleep();
println("second message <after the delay>");
```

More info here:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep(long)

Comment: this works. But I want to just have it as a delay and be able to add additional commands before and after it. I dont want any print methods in my runnable

Comment: Thread.sleep will "delay" the thread which is currently in scope. However if the current thread is the UI thread it will block that, which will cause your UI freeze for that time. Sorry, if you made it more clear what your goal is, I could give a better answer.

Comment: This makes sense, but how would I change it so that its not on the UI thread? Sorry Im really new to this! :)

Comment: That's when you have to start your calculation or whatever you're doing in a new thread. That't pretty much what you're doing up there.

Comment: Well, it's still not clear to me what you're trying to do. Please write in detail the use case.